# Omnis Obdc non-unicode Driver

Tags: ftp, odbc, driver, non-unicode

I'm trying to connect Omnis to a database via ODBC

So on their web site: https://www.tigerlogic.com/tigerlogic/omnis/download/tools.jsp
i have found then needed driver (Non-Unicode Driver)

but when i'm trying to download it (ftp://ftp.tigerlogic.com/public/ODBCDriver/Win3264/Omnis-ODBC-Driver.exe)
i get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

and i can't find it elsewhere.

Comment: can i get some advices to connect omnis data file (df1) on my java application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They had to move their FTP site on Monday so They didn't have an up to date link
so the new address i used to download the driver is : ftp://50.16.196.15